# MySQL join on only part of a field using Substring and Like

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have two tables that look like this:

```
node:
NID    Name
1      Chicago
2      New York
3      LA

url_alias:
src    dst
user/1    user/Bob
user/2    user/Mike
node/1    node/chicago
node/2    node/new-york
node/3    node/LA
```

etc

Basically, the url_alias table has alias urls that my webserver redirects to.  Both nodes and users have 'ids' as seen in the url.  I am trying to join my node table to the url_alias table and match on the stuff after the '/' (the node id).  So far I have this code, but it only uses substring and not like so it also matches any users that  end in the correct number:

```
select `node`.`nid` AS `nid`,`node`.`name` AS `name`,`url_alias`.`src` AS `srcurl`,`url_alias`.`dst` AS `dsturl`
from ((`node` join `url_alias` on ((`node`.`nid` = substring(`url_alias`.`src`,6)))))
order by `node`.`nid` desc
```

(actually the query is a bit longer as it also joins another table, which is working, but I have edited it for simplicity)

This query returns results like this:

```
nid    name      srcurl    dsturl

1      chicago   node/1    node/chicago
1      chicago   user/1    user/Bob
2      new-york   node/1    node/new-york
2      new-york   user/1    user/Mike
```

Is there a way to use "LIKE 'node/%'" within my query, or something similar to only grab 'nodes' before substring runs its matching?

Comment: Tips: the brackets are not necssary for surrounding joins. MySQL is far more forgiving of join syntax than other dbs (eg mssql), and backticks on fields are only necessary if the field name is a reserved word.

Comment: best way to do is to restructure your table by adding `ID` on table `url_alias`.

Comment: I was considering adding the ID to the table, but sometimes that ID refers to uid (user id from the user table) and other times it refers to nid (node id from the node table), so it would likely need to add both those columns to the url_alias table, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `on` portion of a join is essentially just a `where` clause. Anything you can specify in a `where` will work in an ON, so...

```
JOIN x ON somefield LIKE 'node%' AND node.nid = SUBSTRING(src, 6)
```

is perfectly acceptable. Note that since you're using the substring operation, use of indexes will not be possible - indexes do not work on derived data. You would be far better off normalizing your data and splitting that 'id' portion into its own field.

Comment: I keep getting 'unknown column 'node%' when I use "join `url_alias` on ((`url_alias`.`src` LIKE `node%`) AND (`node`.`nid` = substring(`url_alias`.`src`,6))) order by `node`.`nid` desc"

Comment: you're sprinkling backticks around where they're not needed. like clauses use `'` quotes. stop quoting everything because there's no point to it.

Comment: Thanks Marc, you're right.  I was following a (rather poor) example online that used the backticks for some reason.  Thanks for your help